# Twilio Delete channel in subaccount using REST API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm able to delete a programmable chat channel using REST API:

DELETE https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISxxx/Channels/CHxxx

I'm able to get a subaccount info:

GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxx

How can I delete a channel in a subaccount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Twilio support told me, subaccounts work the same way as accounts. I just had to authenticate using the subaccount credentials.

Subaccount SID + auth token

OR

API key + secret belonging to subaccount